# How to make UI element render behind object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, 2d, rendering

I have a badge animation that has a child of text and then a button that decreases the level that should always appear behind the score badge.

I have tried a lot of things(like sorting layer component but then the badge renders over all UI elements even its child text) but fundamentally I changed the Decrease level and Text to just be Default for the layer option and set the Z position and scale to 0. I have then changed the Score Badge and its child to be layer UI and negative coordinates so they appear in front of the camera but the issue still persists.

Here is the editor hierarchy
[image: Hiearchy image]

The issue I am having is the rendering looks like this:
[image: ScoreBadge Issue]
[image: A dynamic View of the rendering issue]
[image: Gameplay Example]

Comment: are you using sprite? or just UI image elements only?

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII The Decrease Level is a Button that has a child of text and the Score Badge object is an animated sprite with a child of text

Comment: To blend sprites with ui elements use Screen Space - Camera in the Canvas.renderMode.

Comment: Screen Space - Overlay will always render UI elements in front of sprites.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII I do have my render mode set to Screen Space - Camera. An issue is I want the UI element for the level button to behind the sprite (the badge) while the the sprites text is in front of all of them.

Comment: if you want sprite (the badge) in front of UI element try to move the z position of the sprite to negative value.

Comment: When you set render mode to Screen Space - Camera then the position of gameobject matters. the one that is near the camera will always render in front.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII If you look at the gif above with me moving in the editor even with the X position changed and stacked properly the UI elements button still displays in front

Comment: As I can see, the text is on front, but the hex image is behind. It can be due to some specifics of shader rendering your image (sprite, texture, text, svg,  idk what is this hex). If you want a quick solution, try to create another canvas and put the badge inside it, the canvas can be inside the the main one or a separate one.

Comment: Ah Thank you! This worked (kinda I use the canvas and messed around with sliders.) In the end these were my final settings for anyways else who comes:
Button Object( Layer: Default Z-Pos 12) then under it in the hierarchy was the canvas(Layer UI and child were also Layer UI) with all Z Pos 0 and Sorting Layer: UI with  Order 34.  The Badge was Default sorting layer order 30 Z pos -13. Child Text was Z pos 2. Sorry for the bad formatting comments arent great for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Layers try dragging it in sorting layers the one in the bottom of the stack will render in front.